# Overleaf works fine/ TexStudio doesn't: Getting ghsystem/chemmacros to work in TeXStudio

Tags: miktex, texstudio, overleaf, chemmacros

So due to an abundance of projects and needing a folder structure, I am finally migrating from overleaf. I had this project working fine in overleaf and managed to get as far as to find out that some interaction between ghsystem and chemmacros seem to be causing trouble.

The weird things is. Overleaf compiles just fine. TexStudio give me a fatal error:

```
Zeile 669: Missing \begin{document}. \chemmacros_load_module:n {n
: No file texstudio_htgYAH.aux.
: You haven't loaded any package for upright Greek(chemmacros) letters or no unique choice was possible. Either(chemmacros) load one of packages specified in the manual or(chemmacros) select a chemgreek mapping manually.
Zeile 9: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

This is a minimal(ish) working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{chemmacros}
\usepackage{ghsystem} 
    \begin{document}
        \ghspic[scale=1]{acid}
        \ghs{h}{315}\\
        %\ghs{h}{318}\\
        %\ghs{h}{335}
    \end{document}
```

I would be happy with any help as I am very new with TexStudio. Overleaf was a little more idiot-proof I guess...

Comment: Note that texstudio has nothing to do with this. It's your latex installation. Texstudio is just calling latex

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cgnieder/ghsystem/issues/13
had an answer for the issue. Seems that TexStudio using more recent packages than overleaf was causing the trouble.

Quick solution:

`Commenting out the line \chemmacros_load_module:n {nomenclature} in ghsystem.sty will fix the problem.`